# drupalgap compile for android and ios doesnt load tabs

Tags: android, ios, cordova, drupal, phonegap-build

I have a problem where when I compile drupalgap, (followed the tutorial on Compiling_a_Mobile_Application) I don't get the tabs when I deploy to the simulator.

As per the tutorial, I should get this output:
[image: click to see image]

but instead, I get this output:
[image: click to see image]

I'm at a loss cause there's no error, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. If anyone has encountered this issue before please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?  I've got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before compiling or publishing our app, You need to setup the development environment to launch the app
[visit this link and follow the procedure](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Compiling_a_Mobile_Application/Preparing_PhoneGap/Installing_PhoneGap)

Comment: I did, based on the procedures at the link, i followed every step. My build was also successful with no errors which is why i find myself at a loss. Can i develop locally and publish to the emulator with my drupal instance on localhost or does it have to be on a www address on the net?